# Finding the taylor series for a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the taylor series for $f(x)=(x-1)^3$ centered at $x=0$

Calculating derivative and evaluating them for $x=0$ we see that any derivative greater than and including the 5th derivative is 0.

So would the taylor series for this be,

$$\sum\frac{0x^2}{n!}=0$$

And then since the taylor series is $0$ when calculating the radius of convergence would it just be $\infty$ since when you use the ratio test for $\sum\frac{0x^2}{n!}=0$ you would get $lim=0$ therefore for all $x$ the series converges and the radius is $\infty$

Comment: Taylor series just has 5 terms, not infinite in this case.

Comment: the ratio test cannot be used if some coefficient is zero frequently.

Comment: Well, even the fourth derivative is 0.  So no $x^4$ term or any higher one.  The whole series is not 0 though, some of the lower powers are non-zero.  Calculate those lower derivatives and you can write down the full power series.  Now multiply out $(x - 1)^3$ and compare them.

Comment: @badjohn but don't you have to consider $f^n(0)=0$? so then how would the series not be 0

Comment: Let's look at the first term in the Taylor series: $f(0)$ - that's $-1$ so the series starts with $-1$.  I calculate $f'(0)$ as 3 so the next term is $3x$.  So, although all terms of the series are zero after a while, the first few are not: $-1 + 3x + ?x^2 + ?x^3$.  Try to figure out the ?s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(0)=3(x-1)^2\bigg\vert_{x=0}=3$,  $\;f''(0)=6(x-1)\bigg\vert_{x=0}=-6$,  $\;f'''(x)=6=f'''(0)$, $\;f^{(4)}(x)=0$. So the Taylor's series  of $(x-1)^3\;$ centred at $0$ is simply
$$(x-1)^3=-1+3x-3x^2+x^3,$$
which you might have guessed by the binomial formula.

More generally, a polynomial is its own Taylor's series centred at $0$, and its radius of convergence is trivially  infinite.